# Far Manager show line numbers in file editor

Tags: far-manager

Is it possible to do something like vim's `:set number` but in Far Manager 3 editor/viewer?

I want to be able to see line number and line of text instead of just text.

Is there a plugin or some option for that in the configuration?

Comment: AFAIK is not possible in standard FAR. I couldn't find any plugin for this either. You can try your luck in the Far Manager forum: https://forum.farmanager.com/viewforum.php?f=26 (or the Russian forum if you can speak the language)

Answer (score 1):

Try use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> in Far Editor

Comment: Suggestion - you could improve your answer by explaining it or giving a reference to ti.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I opened a file using `F3` and then tried to press `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`B` but it didn't show me line numbers. Do you use some extension for this purpose, maybe I don't have it.